# Nginx connect to server with required CA

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate, authorization, ca

I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy towards a server (server A) that requires the client (my nginx proxy) to have an ssl certificate (self) signed by a given CA.

I've searched a lot online, but I found no option to do this in nginx. My current nginx configuration contains this:

```
ssl_certificate     /path_to_certs/https.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /path_to_certs/https.key;
```

which simply tells nginx which ssl key/certificate to use for the clients. I can connect to server A with the command:

```
curl -k --key /path_to_certs/https.key --cert /path_to_certs/https.cer https://serverA
```

but when I try to connect through nginx reverse proxy ("curl -k  https://nginx_proxy") I get "400 No required SSL certificate was sent" (this is the forwarded response of server A).

How can I get this working? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` to specify the certificates to use to authenticate against the server. And you might need to use `proxy_ssl_server_name`. See also https://www.robertkehoe.com/2016/07/nginx-proxy-pass-resolving-no-required-ssl-certificate-was-sent/

Comment: Oh great, I was expecting it to be so simple, but I really missed this option when reading nginx documentation. Really thanks!